# Objective-C calculations with values passed through segue not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, segue

A simple question, hopefully. Why am I getting **0**'s for **lostWagesLabel** and **totalNeedLabel** - two values calculated in the following code?

**EDIT: Original question replaced entirely with the following code - updated based on suggestions received so far:**

Three values are passed through a segue from a parent scene to this scene. And all three values appear correctly when shown as text values in this scene. But only one of the values (Weeks) appears correctly when I run NSLog - which means the other two values are going into the calculations as 0's.

Here are the declarations in the parent scene:

```
IBOutlet UISlider *earningsSlider;
IBOutlet UILabel *earningsLabel;
IBOutlet UISlider *disabledSlider;
IBOutlet UILabel *disabledLabel;
IBOutlet UISlider *expensesSlider;
IBOutlet UILabel *expensesLabel;
```

And here is a sample of the implementation:

```
- (IBAction)earningsSlide:(id)sender {
    NSNumberFormatter *commas = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    commas.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    int earningsValue = (int)(earningsSlider.value / 1000.0);
    [earningsSlider setValue:earningsValue * 1000.0];
    earningsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", 
                         [commas stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:earningsValue * 1000]]];
}
```

Here is where everything is passed through the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DisabilitySegue"]) {
        DisabilityViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.earningsNumber = self->earningsLabel.text;
        destViewController.expensesNumber = self->expensesLabel.text;
        destViewController.disabledNumber = self->disabledLabel.text;
    }
}
```

Here are the declarations in the new scene:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *earningsLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *earningsNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *expensesLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *expensesNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *disabledLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *disabledNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *message;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lostWages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lostWagesLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *totalNeed;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *totalNeedLabel;
```

And here is the implementation in its current state:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSNumberFormatter *commas = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    commas.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
    earningsLabel.text = earningsNumber;
    expensesLabel.text = expensesNumber;
    disabledLabel.text = disabledNumber;
    int earn = [earningsNumber intValue];
    int expense = [expensesNumber intValue];
    int weeks = [disabledNumber intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d %d %d",earn,expense,weeks);
    //print values to console
    int lost = (int)(earn / 52 * weeks);
    int need = (int)(expense * 12 / 52 * weeks);
    NSLog(@"%d %d",lost,need);
    //print values to console
    lostWages = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",
                        [commas stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:lost]]];
    totalNeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",
                        [commas stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:need]]];
    lostWagesLabel.text = lostWages;
    totalNeedLabel.text = totalNeed;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The NSLog looks like this when I run it using the smallest amounts possible of 1000, 100 & 1 for *earnings*, *expenses* and *disabled*(*weeks*) in the parent scene:

**2012-08-17 09:01:38.277 MyApp[8117:15203] 0 0 1**

**2012-08-17 09:01:38.279 MyApp[8117:15203] 0 0**

I'm also trying to change the format of what's being sent through the segue with this as the declarations in the parent scene:

```
@interface IncomeProtectionViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UISlider *earningsSlider;
    IBOutlet UISlider *expensesSlider;
    IBOutlet UISlider *disabledSlider;
    IBOutlet UILabel *earningsLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *expensesLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *disabledLabel;
    NSNumber *earningsNumber;
    NSNumber *expensesNumber;
    NSNumber *disabledNumber;
}
```

And this in the implementation:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DisabilitySegue"]) {
        DisabilityViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.earningsNumber = self->earningsNumber;
        destViewController.expensesNumber = self->expensesNumber;
        destViewController.disabledNumber = self->disabledNumber;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting incompatibility warnings over in the destination scene.

Comment: Have you debugged it?  Are these numbers being pulled over properly?  Are you getting a proper float value out of them?

Comment: Can you provide some sample values that might be found in earningsNumber, expensesNumber, and disabledNumber?

Comment: NSLog the values of those variables and see what they are. As a side note, if the values that you're casting to `int` are less than 0 they'll get truncated to 0.

Comment: The app compiles with no errors. The calculated and other numbers all appear properly formatted - except the calculated numbers show up as $0. Values that can be selected for earningsNumber range from 0 to 150,000 in increments of 1,000; for expensesNumber from 0 to 12,000 by 1,000's; and for disabledNumber from 0 to 52 in whole numbers. I'm still fairly new to Xcode. I haven't done an NSLog yet. I'll see if I can figure out how. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: To save time - if the first 3 values are 100,000, 5,000 and 10; then the 2 calculated values should be 19,230 and 11,538.

Comment: Might I assume that the title and tag changes H2CO3 made initially gave this question a better chance of being found and responded to than what I had used (Xcode, calc - no objective-c or cocoa)?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems here.

First, never, ever, *ever*, use `float` or similar types for currency or other exact values.  You *will* get wrong answers in calculations.  This is what `NSDecimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` were created to address.

This leads to another question: what are you trying to do with your math?:

```
int need = (int)(expense * 12 / 52 * weeks);
```

OK, so you've done some floating point math, then cast the result to an `int`.  (Normally you'd probably want to use NSInteger, but we'll set that aside.)  This means that any values less than 1 will get rounded down to zero, which could be your problem right there, depending on your inputs.  (My guess is this is where your problem lies; use the debugger to examine your values!)

```
totalNeed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",
                    [commas stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:need]]];
```

So, in light of the above, why are you using `+numberWithFloat:` when you have an `int`?  I don't think this will break on its own, but it's still not really correct.

As an aside, I'm guessing that your integer literals (12 and 52) are coming from the calendar (12 months per year, 52 weeks per year).  If not, you can ignore this, but if they are then this is also wrong: not all years have 52 weeks, not all years have 12 months (for some definition of month).  You should not hardcode such values, but use the various [date and time functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) to do math as required.

Finally, if you are not using ARC, you are leaking `commas`.

**Follow-Up**

Looking at your updated code, I have a few more questions:

```
int earningsValue = (int)(earningsSlider.value / 1000.0);
[earningsSlider setValue:earningsValue * 1000.0];
```

What's this supposed to do?  Aren't you just setting back the  same value (albeit with some imprecision potentially introduced)?

```
destViewController.earningsNumber = self->earningsLabel.text;
```

This is *not* the correct way to access a property or instance variable of an object.  `->` dereferences a member of a struct pointer.  You presumably want to use `self.earningsLabel` or `[self earningsLabel]`.

Finally, it is generally ill-advised to intermingle your view with your model.  For example, here you seem to be using label text as a representation of your backing data, which then forces a lot of type conversion, among other things.  It would be better for you to have a model object, probably using `NSDecimalNumber` for backing storage, and update your views all from the model.

Comment: Using Xcode 4.3.2, Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting is set to the default of Yes. I was afraid this wasn't the most correct or concise code. I've been developing the app by finding similar examples and tutorials and modifying them to fit my needs. And the calculations I've done so far are coming out correct (though very basic - like 500 * 12 / 52). Nothing ever ends up below 1. The first calculation you listed takes a monthly expense amount and expresses it in weekly terms which is then multiplied by the weeks value. For these calculations, the hardcoded numbers work fine.

Comment: Regarding the incorrect methods I'm using, I wouldn't ask you to rewrite it correctly. But, perhaps, you could point me toward some useful references. The books and online materials I've found are limited in how much they can help in this respect.

Comment: WHERE IS THE 2ND ANSWER? We were onto something there and the whole thing just disappeared. NSLog had shown that values weren't transferring into the calculations properly and I asked for help formatting what was transferred in the segue into something that would work in the formulas.

Comment: @steveald I guess the answerer deleted it? Anyhow, as for your question above, I'm not sure which incorrect methods your are referring to. The gold standard for most things are the class docs. For example, at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html, you can see there is a `+numberWithInt:` method you might use.

Comment: @steveald And I agree that the code might work now, but *not all years have 52 weeks* - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date for examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've looked at the Developer Libraries trying to solve issues and, due to my lack of training, usually found I needed to see all the code in a real-world example to be able to adopt it into my app. Unfortunately, that sometimes leads to some ugly coding, such as: Mixing float and int variables (the incorrect methods I was referring to). I understand your point, but the 12 & 52 thing is really no more complicated than converting one's monthly income into a weekly amount. So I should be fine with that. But thanks for the concern.

Comment: So, this is where I'm at. The relevant code in the parent scene that passes the values through the segue looks like this: `destViewController.earningsNumber = self->earningsLabel.text;`          In the code above, lines like this allow me to correctly display the passed values in the destination scene: `earningsLabel.text = earningsNumber;`          BUT NSLog revealed an amount only for _weeks_ - not _earn_, _expense_, _lost_ or _need_. Which means 0's in the calculations. I need to correctly format what gets passed through the segue so it will work in the calculations. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to change all instances of _float_ to _int_, but NSLog still says only _weeks_ is passing a value. Any ideas? Could it be the format in which _earningsNumber_, etc. were passed through the segue? Even though _earningsLabel_, etc. all display correctly?

Comment: I have completely replaced the original question with updated code and everything I can think of that's relevant to the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I've just been too busy to look at StackOverflow lately. If no one else gets to it first I'll try taking a look this weekend.

Comment: Thanks. You've really been the only one with an answer. I'm trying to change the format of what gets passed through the segue, but incompatibility warnings are slowing me down.

Comment: @steveald Please see new comments.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. To explain what's going on, there are 3 sliders on the initial scene where the user can select numbers that will be used in calculations whose results appear on the second scene. They are passed through the segue as: earningsNumber, expensesNumber & disabledNumber. The ranges and increments are described in the comments after my original question. The "/ 1000" and "* 1000" bits you asked about limit the sliders for the first two values to increments of 1000. The third slider is limited to whole numbers.

Comment: I got the sliders scene to work perfectly and the values did pass through the segue as useable text because I was able to get them to appear on the second scene, but the passed values aren't useable for calculations.  --   My whole experience with objective-c and Xcode has been through a few books and a lot of online tutorials and sample code that accomplish close enough to what I want to do for me to be able to figure out how to make them work for me. That's why you see a lot of what you called  "intermingl[ing] your view with your model". And that appears to be what's stopping me here.

Comment: I have tried formatting the values before and after the segue with variations of NSNumber, but not NSDecimalNumber - as you can see in the last two code samples I added to my original question.  ---  It has just occurred to me that I should do the calculations in the first scene and pass those values through the segue. I can get values to appear that way. But, as you said, I'm not formatting them correctly, so I really wouldn't be coding properly if I continue the way I'm going now. If you have any suggestions on how to properly format the code you see above, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Conrad, could you take another look at this? I really need to get it resolved and you've offered the most help. Thanks.